# How do you stop trains in GTA 5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I am planning a prank on my friend which requires me to stop a train. I have tried several methods including:

1. Blocking the train with a car
2. Shooting the drivers

Neither of them worked. Thus, I would like to know the answers to the following questions:

**Is it even possible to stop the train? If yes, what are the ways? Do they need to be in a specific area to be stopped?**

[image: http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/LNACSZiu2q0/hqdefault.jpg]

Comment: Short of hijacking the train (which I am not sure is possible outside of one particular mission), I cannot think of any way to stop a train, given the way that trains work.

Comment: Am I the only one who wants to know what the prank is?

Comment: I tried with 20 sticky bombs (which is the limit in story mode) all on the front (engine) of the train but it still did not work and I did not miss any

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only current way to stop a train is to use explosives on the engine.

If interested, [here](https://youtu.be/VeMeLMYOKaI?t=3m55s) is a fairly entertaining video of a few guys finally stopping a train.

Comment: Also note that this is only working with sticky bombs. Grenades won't work.

Comment: @CédricD Thanks for the info - I only tried it with stickies, do you know if the RPG works? I suspect if that works, the tank rounds and jet missiles will also be effective.

Comment: I think it wouldn't work, because the point with stickies is that you can cause multiple explosions at once (this is just a guess here). But it would worth a try, stopping a train with a jet would be awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is blow up the front of the train using a sticky bomb.

Comment: Could you expand on this answer?  For instance, could you suggest a weapon or method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't hijack a train but sticky bombs do work on stopping the train - but blowing up vehicles can put you on bad sport. I tried all things to stop it: a tank, jet, and a bus, but the train won.

Comment: only destroying other player's insured vehicles will give you bad sport warnings

Answer (score 0):

the only possible way is sticky bombs on front but rockstar patched it so it won't stop and making it extremely hard but trying to take us away from something secret...